# Can I animate an object to move behind a transparent image plane and be invisible?

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, transparency

I have a small simple animated scene.  I have a transparent image plane so the background still shows through with an illustrated graphic, but there is an object that I would like to have move behind it and be hidden behind the plane.  Is this possible since the image plane will be transparent?  Thanks for any constructive advice or tips

Answer (score 1):

you can use this node setup here:

[image]

by moving the plane you make it invisible.

[image]

I colored the plane red to see what's going on. Of course you would make it invisible.

Comment: Great thank you!!